# I need to reformat an output file into columns

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text file formatted like:

```
cn: ressync2gb
description: MailBox SYNC 2GB
zimbraFileMaxSize: 2147483648
zimbraId: 776bghb4396edc
zimbraQuota: 2147483648
cn: ressync3gb
description: MailBox SYNC 3GB
zimbraFileMaxSize: 2147483648
zimbraId: 22420a29
zimbraQuota: 3221225472
```

and I am trying to reformat the second field into columns.

What I tried

```
awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS); print $2}' allcos.txt | column -t
```

What I expect:

```
cn           description          zimbraFileMaxSize        zimbraId         zimbraQuota
ressync2gb   MailBox SYNC 2GB     2147483648               776bghb4396edc   2147483648
ressync3gb   MailBox SYNC 3GB     2147483648               22420a29         3221225472
```

Comment: No, this output is in rows, and I need to convert to columns.  Thanks

Comment: will each `cn` group be guarantted to have exactly 5 lines? and will the 5 lines always be in the same order (based on the first field)?

Comment: sample data shows both `cn` blocks with 5 lines, but the current `awk` code appears to be based on a `cn` block containing exactly 3 lines (`NR%3`) ... was this a typo or are we missing some details?

Comment: Typo.  There are 5 fields in the output.

Using Etuardu's corrections I now get the records cn value on the following record at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F": " '{ORS=(NR%5?"\t":RS); print $2}' allcos.txt                                                                  
ressync2gb  MailBox SYNC 2GB    2147483648  776bghb4396edc  2147483648
ressync3gb  MailBox SYNC 3GB    2147483648  22420a29    3221225472
```

Comment: Ok, this is super close.  Some records (with longer strings) get a bit wonky. Is one of those values the field length?

Here is an example:


```
cn: demo
description: All Features for Demo Accounts
zimbraFileUploadMaxSizePerFile: 2147483648
zimbraId: 1a9111641d-0341-463f-9c94-0d32fd43328c
zimbraMailQuota: 10737418240```

Comment: Here is the output I get now:

Commercial Blackberry 1 GB      2147483648      e36c7740-a36a-4ede-xxxx-8c0e0c9bbd18    1073741824      commblackberry2gb
Commercial Blackberry 2 GB      2147483648      496428ec-179d-4c0e-yyyy-55cdbacd331d    7516192768      commblackberry3gb
Commercial Blackberry 3 GB      2147483648      3d4c0ec2-60f0-4044-zzzz-7c61597f99ed    8589934592      commblackberry4gb
Commercial Blackberry 4 GB      2147483648      8a906d77-7503-4c0e-0000-535064c5dd9b    9663676416      commblackberry5gb

The name is on the second row of the next record.

Comment: The command that you used, which I fixed, is based on the assumption that you always have the same amount of repeating fields. In your original input you had 5 fields. Now you are reporting an example containing 4 fields, which moreover are different from the previous ones. If your input does not satisfy that assumption, you have to change approach, and if you want help you need to provide a better input sample.

Comment: @dj423 please update the question with these additional sample inputs; not everyone will read through comments to piece together the whole/bigger picture; also, formatting is lost in comments so it's hard(er) to understand the (new) issue

Comment: Thanks Etuartu.  The output file had a field missing in one of the records throwing it off.  I added the 5th field, and it formats perfect.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk -F ': ' 'BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc" }
    /cn: / { ++i } { a[$1, i] = $2 } !b[$1] { b[$1] = ++j } 
    END { for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j) {
        for (k in b) printf "%s\t", j ? a[k, j] : k; print ""
    } }' file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Output:

```
cn          description       zimbraFileMaxSize  zimbraId        zimbraQuota  
ressync2gb  MailBox SYNC 2GB  2147483648         776bghb4396edc  2147483648   
ressync3gb  MailBox SYNC 3GB  2147483648         22420a29        3221225472
```

- This expects data to not have two instances of `:`  in a line. String manipulation would need to be used instead.
- `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` can also be excluded and a generic awk can be used instead but it would require storing key in another indexed array variable and code becomes more verbose.
- A `RS="cn: "` solution can be used instead but it expects data format to be consistent and it's boring.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
data=$<.map{|line| line.split(/:[[:blank:]]*/,2)}.
each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}){|(k,v),h| h[k]<<v.chomp }

tbl=CSV.generate(**{:headers=>false, :col_sep=>"\t"}){ |csv|
    csv<<data.keys
    data.values.transpose.each{|row| csv<<row}
}
puts tbl' file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Prints:

```
cn          description       zimbraFileMaxSize  zimbraId        zimbraQuota
ressync2gb  MailBox SYNC 2GB  2147483648         776bghb4396edc  2147483648
ressync3gb  MailBox SYNC 3GB  2147483648         22420a29        3221225472
```